# Special characters break Json

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to work with Jsons containing loads of special characters and spaces. I've read somewhere else here on stack that the Gson library (for Java) does a very good job so I'm using that. While using the fromJson(Json string, object class) method to turn a Json string into an object, I noticed that as soon as the data in the string contains any special character or white space, an exception is thrown (Unterminated object). Removing the special characters makes it work as intended.

To better exemplify the situation:

```
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

Person p1 = new Person("Matteo", 999);
Person p2 = new Person("Adam", 999);
Person p3 = new Person("Steve", 999);

people.add(p1);
people.add(p2);
people.add(p3);

String json = new Gson().toJson(people);
System.out.println(json);

ArrayList people2 = new Gson().fromJson(json, ArrayList.class);

for (int i = 0; i < people2.size(); i++) {
    Person pn = new Gson().fromJson(people2.get(i).toString(), Person.class);
    System.out.println(people2.get(i).toString());
    System.out.println(pn.name);
}
```

```java
class Person {

    String name;
    int age;

    Person(String cname, int cage) {
        name = cname;
        age = cage;
    }
}
```

The code above works as intended, BUT if instead of Matteo I type Ma:tteo or Ma tteo or any other string that contains special characters then it breaks.

So is there a way to circumvent this issue? Alternatively is there a better solution than using this library?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the JSON?

Comment: You have probably either messed up your character encoding, or have invalid Json. What code do you use to read contents to the `String`?

Comment: My guess is that there are issues with character encoding. There are rules to define whether a string is a valid JSON string or not, and I believe Gson does its job.

Comment: you need to add example of code and JSON

Comment: Personally, I prefer to use the `org.json` library. For example, you can use [this](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) or [AOSP JSON library (1)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/f0d4a04/json/src/main/java/org/json), [(2)](https://github.com/kbsriram/android-json)

Comment: @RobAu tell me more about the character encoding. I'm almost positive the Json is valid because in the example I provided above it works as intended, but as soon as a special character is inserted everything breaks. So maybe the issue is character related.

Comment: @congard I'll definitely give it a go. Thanks.

Comment: @MCEmperor I'll have a look at it, is there any industry standard I should be aware of? Or is it a case by case thing? Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MatteoBaldini Could you post the output of `System.out.println(json)`?

Comment: I'm surprised it worked in your first attempt anyway. You are unserializing the JSON string twice, the first time using a possible non-overridden `toString()` method. Or have you implemented the `Person.toString()` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Gson` does its work fine.

There are two problems with how you are using the Gson library:

- You are using `fromJson(String, Class<T>)` in conjunction with generics. The documentation states that when using generics, you should use `fromJson(String, Type)`:

  > For the cases when the object is of generic type, invoke `fromJson(String, Type)`.
- You are first deserializing the JSON string into a Java structure – in your case an `ArrayList` – and then you are looping over it, and for each object, you are deserializing it again, relying on the `toString()` method of the object contained in the `ArrayList`. As a matter of fact, your list does not contain `Person` objects at all, instead, it contains `LinkedTreeMap` objects from the `com.google.gson.internal` package. You can get the object's class by calling `people2.get(i).getClass()`.

You really don't need to walk over the elements of this `ArrayList` and deserialize the elements yourself. If it was required to walk over each list contained in your structure, it would be a world of hurt when that structure was more complex than yours.

Simply get rid of your for-loop and replace your `toJson(String, Class<T>)` call with a call to `fromJson(String, Type)`. That's all.

```
// We're using the TypeToken class, to handle generic types
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Person>>() { }.getType();
List<Person> newPeople = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);

// Print all names
newPeople.stream()
    .map(t -> t.name)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

**Notes**

- A part of the source of the problem is that you are using a *[raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)* (`ArrayList`). Don't use raw types, they are only allowed for backward compatibility.
- > I need to work with Jsons containing loads of special characters and spaces.

  It's still not clear what you mean with special characters. The [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) clearly defines what is allowed and what is not. Your JSON string should follow the standards, and then you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code.

```
    ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

    Person p1 = new Person("Ma:tteo", 999);
    Person p2 = new Person("Adam", 999);
    Person p3 = new Person("Steve", 999);

    people.add(p1);
    people.add(p2);
    people.add(p3);


    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(people);
    System.out.println(json);

    List<Person> personList = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Person>>(){}.getType());

    for (int i = 0; i < personList.size(); i++) {
        Person person = personList.get(i);
        System.out.println(person.toString());
        System.out.println(person.name);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, your solution also works great, but I confirmed the one above because it's more informative.